# Count from a number to a target number script and use it in multiple boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

### I found that on another topic:

```
$({
    countNum: $('.skill-counter').text()
}).animate({
    countNum: 90
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function () {
        $('.skill-counter').text(Math.floor(this.countNum) + 1 + ('%'));
    }
});
```

What I am trying to change with this is to put this in a function and use it in multiple boxes with different count values.

### What I have done so far:

```
var count = function (counTo, divName) {
    this.counTo = 0;
    $(counTo).animate({
        counTo: counTo
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function () {
            $(divName).text(Math.floor(counTo) + 1 + ('%'));
        }
    });
};

count(90, 'box1');
count(70, 'box2');
count(50, 'box3');
```

It doesn't work and probably that's normal because it's totally wrong! So How can I do that?

Comment: Change `'boxN'` to `'.boxN'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var count = function (countTo, divName) {
    //Set the starting object as {countTo:0}
    $({countTo: 0}).animate({countTo: countTo}, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function () {
            //get the reference to the value using 'this'
            $(divName).text(Math.floor(this.countTo) + 1 + ('%'));
        }
    });
};

//Pass resolvable selectors
count(90, '#box1');
count(70, '#box2');
count(50, '#box3');
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKM29/)**

Comment: please post an explanation so that someone coming across this will understand why you did what you did. Thanks!